# Deleting records from Master- Details tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following the very kind answers to my last question a short while ago I'd now like to clean up the tables from which I have just transferred records to the historical data tables of those records I'd just transferred.

I know that DELETE FROM  will delete all of the records which clearly I don't want to do so I will need to condition it with a where statement.

What I have to date is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [HistoricalData].[ClearAllLandingInformation]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@cutoffdate date
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
DELETE FROM Landings.LandingDetails
WHERE INNER JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders
            ON Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingId = Landings.LandingDetails.LandingId
        WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate

DELETE FROM Landings.LandingHeaders
WHERE LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate
GO
```

The error message when I try to execute the sql and therefore create the procedure is telling me that the syntax is wrong near the word INNER (either with or without brackets).  Is it simply a case of poor syntactical construction on my part or can you not delete records from a details table based on a condition in the master table?

Finally, working on the assumption for present that it's my sql syntax that is bad is there anything fundamentally wrong with creating a procedure that would first transfer the records from the current tables to the historical tables and then go on to delete those records that were transferred from the current table.  My ultimate goal would be to produce a stored procedure that could be imported into an entity model and executed as a single function by the end user.

Thanks

Here is my attempt at a combined spoc to both move and then delete records that meet a certain criteria.  It succeeds in deleting them from the original tables (the last part) but not in transferring them in the original part.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [HistoricalData].[MoveAndClearLandingInformation] -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@cutoffdate date
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --First collect and move the required information

    INSERT INTO HistoricalData.HistoricalLandingHeaders
            SELECT
                LandingId,
                VesselId,
                TicketNumber,
                LandingDate1,
                PortOfLanding,
                CountryOfLanding,
                Logbook1,
                Loogbook2,
                Logbook3,
                LandingDecNumber1,
                LandingDecNumber2,
                LandingDecNumber3,
                DateOfPurchase,
                Posted,
                AllocatedErsId,
                LandingDate2,
                LandingDate3,
                VesselName,
                VesselOwner,
                VesselPLN,
                ModifiedDate
            FROM Landings.LandingHeaders

            WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate

        INSERT INTO HistoricalData.HistoricalLandingDetails
            SELECT
                LandingDetails.LandingId,
                ProductId,
                PresentationCode,
                PresentationState,
                FreshnessGrade,
                ProductSize,
                FishingArea,
                IcesZone,
                Quantity,
                UnitPrice,
                LandingDetailVatRate,
                SpeciesCode,
                Currency,
                ProductLandedUnderQuota,
                LandingDetails.ModifiedDate


            FROM Landings.LandingDetails
            INNER JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders
                ON Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingId = Landings.LandingDetails.LandingId
            WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate






        --  Now remove that information from the current tables


        DELETE FROM ld
            FROM Landings.LandingDetails ld
            JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders lh
                ON ld.LandingId = lh.LandingId
        WHERE lh.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate

        DELETE FROM Landings.LandingHeaders
        WHERE LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate
    END
```

Comment: `WHERE INNER JOIN` is clearly wrong. Should be `DELETE Landings.LandingDetails FROM Landings.LandingDetails INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 3):

Change your first delete statement to:

```
DELETE FROM Landings.LandingDetails
WHERE LandingId IN 
             ( 
                  SELECT Landings.LandingId
                  FROM Landings.LandingHeaders
                  WHERE Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate
             )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [HistoricalData].[ClearAllLandingInformation]

@cutoffdate DATE

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM ld
    FROM Landings.LandingDetails ld
    JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders lh ON ld.LandingId = lh.LandingId
    WHERE lh.LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate

    DELETE FROM Landings.LandingHeaders
    WHERE LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate

END
```

**Update (if you have FK):**

```
CREATE TABLE Landings.LandingHeaders
(
      LandingId  INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    , LandingDate1 DATETIME
)
CREATE TABLE Landings.LandingDetails(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    LandingId INT NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE Landings.LandingDetails WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LandingId FOREIGN KEY(LandingId)
REFERENCES Landings.LandingHeaders (LandingId)
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE Landings.LandingDetails CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_LandingId
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [HistoricalData].[ClearAllLandingInformation]

    @cutoffdate DATE

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM Landings.LandingHeaders
    WHERE LandingDate1 <= @cutoffdate

END
```

Comment: @Dom Sinclair, I glad to help you :)

Comment: With regard to the second part of the question (as you proved so successfully that it was my syntax that was wrong) is there anything fundamentally wrong with combining statements to move records from the current to historical tables and then statements to delete those records moved from the current tables?

Comment: Do you have a FK between `LandingDetails` and `LandingHeaders`?

Comment: Hi Just added some extra info to my original question so that you can see more clearly the sql that I have at present.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct in SQL Server:

```
WHERE INNER JOIN
```